# How read tag in mp3 file?

Tags: mp3

How can I read the tags in a mp3 file with the help of "Java ID3 Tag Library"? I tried, but nothing happens. Also nothing with example on the "Java ID3 Tag Library" site.

```
BufferedInputStream fs = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
int read = fs.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is, in fact, an example of reading the tags using the Java ID3 Tag Library:

[MP3 Tag java library Quick Start](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/QuickStart.html)

Comment: i try, but nothing. How can i do it?

Comment: @Leks - I can't give you a clearer answer than the documentation. It's complete with copy/paste code examples. If you don't understand the documentation, I would suggest brushing up on your basic java including how to open files.